# parse error unexpected ','

Tags: php, html, mysql, forum

When I run my php script I received the following error:

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in
>   /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/StarFusion/inc2.php on line 11

the code used is :

```
<?php 
    function StarFusion(){ 
        global $mysqli; //connect to server and select the database;    
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "gracieC", "", "testDB"); 
        //if connection fails, stop script execution 
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) { 
           print("connection failed: %s\n", mysqli_connect_error());   
            exit();
        } 
    }
?>
```

Will someone figure me out?

Comment: 1. You include a file without file extension ? 2. `";` typo or in the code? If yes remove it

Answer (score 0):

remove the **;"** at line 4

```
<?php
include ("inc2");
StarFusion(); 


//check for required fields from the form
if((!$_POST["topicAuthor"]) || (!$_POST["topicTitle"]) ||
    (!$_POST["postText"])){
   header ("Location:addtopic.html");
   exit;
   }
```

Comment: the ;" isn't actually there just a typo, still same error without it

Comment: @UniMe Then please update your question with the actual code and also mark the line 29

Comment: I'm now receiving the error: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ',' in /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/htdocs/StarFusion/inc2.php on line 11  the code used is :    <?php
    function StarFusion(){
        global $mysqli;
        
        //connect to server and select the database;
        $mysqli = mysqli_connect ("localhost", "gracieC", "", "testDB");
        
        //if connection fails, stop script execution
        
        if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
            print("connection failed: %s\n" , mysqli_connect_error());
            
            exit();
        }
    }?>

Comment: @UniMe There is a edit button to the bottom left of your question, you are free to use it! http://stackoverflow.com/posts/28729767/edit

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the `";` at the third line shouldn't be there.

Answer (score 0):

Well, the problem is in the line after `StarFusion();`, I can see a double quote there. You don't close it so it causes that the following code is a string.

Comment: Well and I can see that you don't read comments, before you post your answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28729767/parse-error-unexpected#comment45745855_28729792